# Add data to items in Magnific Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I want to add additional data to go along with each additional item in a gallery, in this case a project name in addition to the caption. I have a working version on [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/neslho/pen/ozjIt) (also below) using the `markupParse` callback and storing the Project Name info in a separate array, but it seems like there is probably a more efficient method using the Magnific Popup API. Is there a way to store this information with the `item` object, maybe even have the rendered html be cached?

In the sample code I have created an extra div called `<div class="my-project"></div>` inside the `markup` variable and place the the Project Name data from the `galleryProject` array using the `markupParse` callback.

```
$('#gallery').magnificPopup({

    type: 'image',

    items: [
      {
        src: 'img1.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 1'
      },
      {
        src: 'img2.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 2'
      },
      {
        src: 'img3.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 3'
      }
    ],

    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },

    image: {
      markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
              '<div class="my-project"></div>'+
                  '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                  '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
              '</div>'
    },

    callbacks: {
      markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
        var index = this.currItem.index;
        template.find('.my-project').html( galleryProject[index] );
      }
    }


});

var galleryProject = ['Project 1','Project 2','Project 3'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, this is much simpler way:

```
$('#gallery').magnificPopup({

    type: 'image',

    items: [
      {
        src: 'img1.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 1',
        project: 'Project 1'
      },
      {
        src: 'img2.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 2',
        project: 'Project 2'
      },
      {
        src: 'img3.jpg',
        title: 'Caption 3',
        project: 'Project 3'
      }
    ],

    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },

    image: {
      markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                  '<div class="mfp-project"></div>'+
                  '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                  '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
              '</div>'
    }


});
```

Comment: Aw man thanks so much. That works great. I had tried that before but couldn't get it to work for some reason. Here's the [Codepen](http://cdpn.io/Cbgqh) with that working. Is using `template.find('.my-project').html( item.project );` in the `markupParse` callback the most efficient way to add this data to the popup?

Comment: It doesn't matter much, you may use any technique.

Comment: Just to be clear, any property added to the items objects will be automatically mapped to the html element in the popup with a class equal to "mfp-" plus the property name? It looks like that's how it works on one of your [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/sHoxp) examples too, but didn't see this functionality explicitly mentioned in the documentation.